# Padding of String to fixed size

Tags: c#, string

I want to right align the string value to fixed size let say size must be 3,
so if there is 1 item in string it should be right aligned with added two blanks to the left side and string should be length of 3.
For Example:
`string number ="1"`, after performing the operation it should be `number ="  1"` and if it is `string number ="120"` then leave it as it is no need to left align because length is already `3`.
What is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for System.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string) for anything to do with padding? (Stack Overflow is a great resource, but isn't a replacement for research such as reading documentation.)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PadLeft, if you want the right side, you can use the "PadRight"

```
string value = "12";
value = value.PadLeft(3, ' ');
--result ' 12'
```

define PadLeft

The String PadLeft() method returns a new string of a specified length in which the beginning of the current string is padded with spaces or with a specified character.

PadLeft() Syntax

The syntax of the string PadLeft() method is:

```
PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
```

Answer (score 0):

should be simple enough

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    int paddingSize = 3;
    string stringToPad = "1";
    string paddingString = " ";
    
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(stringToPad);
    for (int i = 0; i < paddingSize - stringToPad.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Insert(0, paddingString);
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**